# JGoodies FormLayout and JWindow

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, jgoodies, form-layout

I have a problem with swing that I cannot resolve since a whole day.
I want to show a popup in `JWindow` if someone types into a `JTextField`.
But if the layout uses a JGoodies `FormLayout` with more components in one row then the display is going to be corrupt.

Do you have any ideas?

Screenshot after typing some letters into the second text field:

[image]

After editing Jans code and typing "a" sowly three times:

[image]

Code in Java:

```
package eu.eyan;

import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JWindow;

import com.jgoodies.forms.factories.CC;
import com.jgoodies.forms.layout.FormLayout;

    public class Snippet {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            JTextField tf = new JTextField(10);

            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setLayout(new FormLayout("p", "p,p,p"));
            panel.add(new JTextField("before"), CC.xy(1, 1));
            panel.add(tf, CC.xy(1, 2));
            panel.add(new JTextField("after"), CC.xy(1, 3));

            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setLayout(new FormLayout("p,p,p", "p"));
            frame.add(new JLabel("bef"), CC.xy(1, 1));
            frame.add(panel, CC.xy(2, 1));
            frame.add(new JLabel("aft"), CC.xy(3, 1));
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.pack();

            JWindow popup = new JWindow();
            popup.setLayout(new FormLayout("p", "p"));
            JLabel l = new JLabel("popup");
            popup.add(l, CC.xy(1, 1));
            popup.pack();

            tf.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                    popup.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is the window packed? BTW `val panel = new JPanel();` What is a `val`? For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Packed: 
  frame.pack-> for the application 
  popup.pack -> for the JWindow popup
val: as i wrote the code is written in Scala.

Comment: It seems the `popup` is not packed until a `KeyEvent` is detected. It **should** be packed before it is made visible!

Comment: The code is in Java now. @Andrew: The location of the pack did not help.

Comment: Huh.. I'm not familiar with that particular layout, so hopefully an expert will be along soon.

Answer (score 1):

The best way how to get help with a layout is providing a sketch of
your UI, either as picture or as ASCII. Here I am only guessing what
you had in mind.

First, `FormLayout` is a good layout; it creates layouts that are portable. Unlike old layouts, like `BoxLayout` or `GridBagLayout`, it uses dialog units instead of pixels. This way a portable layout to various screen sizes can be created. Actually, `FormLayout` was the first Java layout manager that enabled to create truly portable UIs. Other two that can do it are `MigLayout` and `GroupLayout`.

If you can, try using `MigLayout` instead. `MigLayout` was inspired by
`FormLayout` and it significantly improved it. For instance, in `MigLayout` you use set the gaps once, whereas in `FormLayout`, you have
to tediously take the gaps into account when doing your layout.

Corrections:

1) Call the `pack()` method before the `setVisible()` method.

2) Don't use unnecessary panels to create the layout. You probably saw some examples where panels were used to create the layout. This was because managers like `BoxLayout` were so simplistic that we needed
them. With `FormLayout` and `MigLayout`, this is not necessary.

3) You also need to add gaps to your layout in dialogs units.

Here is an example of what I thought you might want to achieve:

```
package com.zetcode.formlayoutex;

import com.jgoodies.forms.factories.CC;
import com.jgoodies.forms.layout.FormLayout;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JWindow;

public class FormLayoutEx {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JTextField tf = new JTextField(10);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new FormLayout("6dlu, p, 5dlu, p:g, 3dlu", 
                "6dlu, p, 4dlu, p, 4dlu, p, 6dlu"));
        frame.add(new JLabel("Before"), CC.xy(2, 2));
        frame.add(new JTextField("before"), CC.xy(4, 2));
        frame.add(tf, CC.xywh(2, 4, 3, 1));
        frame.add(new JLabel("After"), CC.xy(2, 6));
        frame.add(new JTextField("after"), CC.xy(4, 6));


        frame.pack();
        frame.setTitle("FormLayout example");
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        JWindow popup = new JWindow();
        popup.setLayout(new FormLayout("p", "p"));
        JLabel l = new JLabel("popup");
        popup.add(l, CC.xy(1, 1));
        popup.pack();

        tf.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                popup.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but the problem as i mentioned if there are more components in the same line. If you modify your code like this the error still comes:
    frame.add(new JLabel("Middle"), CC.xy(2, 4));//new line
    frame.add(tf, CC.xywh(4, 4, 1, 1));//new constraint

Comment: Hi Jan, see the new screenshot in the question after the line:

After editing Jans code and typing a sowly three times